# Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE does not work on Android 14

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-permissions, android-14

I want to access all folders/files on external storage to display them on screen (like a file manager app) follow [this document](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/manage-all-files#all-files-access)

It worked fine on Android 13 but on 14. On Android 14, the permission launcher always returns false. No error log or exception was thrown. Does anyone know the reason why? It's strange.

```
val permissionLauncher =
        rememberLauncherForActivityResult(contract = ActivityResultContracts.RequestPermission(),
            onResult = {
                when {
                    it -> onPermissionGrant()
                    context.findActivity()
                        ?.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(permissionNeed) == true -> {

                    }

                    else -> onPermissionDenied()
                }
            })

LaunchedEffect(key1 = Unit, block = {  
    permissionLauncher.launch(Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE)
        
    })
```

Comment: This does never work. Also not for 11, 12 and 13. You cannot use RequestPermission() as it is not such.

Comment: @blackapps I have tried on 13 and it worked. 14 didn't work. Why do you talk it never work?

Comment: @TháiQuốcToàn Android has been transitioning to a more restrictive storage model called Scoped Storage. Apps targeting Android 11 and higher are expected to use scoped storage by default. This is what `blackapps` mean

Comment: Go through this blog once https://medium.com/androiddevelopers/android-11-storage-faq-78cefea52b7c

Comment: No it never worked like that. Enabling all files access is done different. Google a bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmm I have realized my mistake in my case. **There is no need to request the Manifest.permission.MANAGE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE permission at runtime**. Just declare it in manifest then start an intent with this action ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION to drive users to the permission settings board and they will turn on directly if they want. That is the way!

Comment: `There is no need to request...` You mean: it's useless..

Comment: They did not mention this in the document to request access all file. Use  ACTION_MANAGE_ALL_FILES_ACCESS_PERMISSION instead @blackapps